# SQLite Mixing logical operators OR and AND in iOS

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, operators

I have this data in an *SQLite* database:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | start_date |  end_date  |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2014-04-22 | 2014-04-22 |
|  2 | 2014-04-22 | null       |
+----+------------+------------+
```

And I'm trying to get both of the rows in an sql like

```c
NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM periods WHERE `start_date` <= ? AND (`end_date` >= ? OR `end_date` IS NULL)";
FMResultSet *set = [db executeQuery:query, date, date];
```

But it only returns the first row.

The exact sql correctly returns both of them in *SQLite Manager* add-on for *Firefox*.

Comment: What code are you using to iterate over the result set?

Comment: There is no need to put column titles inside backquotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all of the rows, you would simply iterate through the whole result set:

```
NSString    *query = @"SELECT * FROM periods WHERE start_date <= ? AND (end_date >= ? OR end_date IS NULL)";
NSString    *date  = @"2014-04-22";
FMResultSet *rs    = [db executeQuery:query, date, date];

while ([rs next]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [rs resultDictionary]);
}
[rs close];
```

This worked fine for me. The problem does not rest in your SQL, but elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I can't believe I put an `if` instead of a `while`